# My links are stretching accross the whole container

Tags: html, css

I have four divs on my page and each one of them has a link. The problem is, I want the links to be the same width and height as the boxes, but for some reason the links stretch more than they should, and as a result the whole container which contains the four divs is clickable.
I've tried setting the anchor tags to `display:inline-block;` but that didn't work.
How do I fix this?

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/noderdowndoop/pen/mdwVKwy)

EDIT: Fixed it by wrapping the anchor tags in divs.

Comment: Please go read [ask] and [mre]. The minimal code necessary to reproduce your problem, belongs directly into your question, and not just dumped onto an external platform.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat&display=swap');
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

:root {
  --nav-clr: #ebebeb;
  --box-r: #f94144;
  --box-g: #43AA8B;
  --box-y: #F9C74F;
  --box-b: #577590;
}

body,
html {
  height: 100vh;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}


/* nav bar  */

nav {
  display: flex;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: var(--nav-clr);
  align-items: center;
}

.logo {
  width: 150px;
  height: auto;
  margin-left: 1em;
}


/* buttons  */

.box-btn {
  /*     margin: 20px; */
  width: auto;
  height: 259px;
  background: #43AA8B;
  border-radius: 30px;
  position: relative;
}

.box-btn::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  /*     margin: 20px; */
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  rightt: 0;
  height: 100px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 30px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 30px;
  background: var(--nav-clr);
  z-index: 1;
}

.content {
  display: grid;
  justify-content: center;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, 250px);
  gap: 20px;
  /* background-color: red; */
}


/* main  */

.main-wrapper {
  height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  justify-content: center;
  grid-template-columns: 80vw;
  grid-template-rows: 25% 5% 65%;
  /*     gap: 20px;  */
}


/* header  */

.title-wrapper {
  margin: 70px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  text-align: center;
  grid-row: 1/3;
}


/* SMALLER SCREENS  */

@media screen and (max-width:700px) {
  .title-wrapper {
    font-size: 1em;
    margin: auto;
  }
  nav {
    justify-content: center;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width:626px) {
  .content {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, 350px);
  }
  .box-btn {
    height: 350px;
  }
  .box-btn::after {
    width: 100%;
    height: 135px;
    bottom: 0;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width:405px) {
  .title-wrapper {
    font-size: .8em;
  }
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>T3 Dashboard</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <nav>
      <a href="http://t3-ks.com/">
        <div class="logo-container">
          <img src="/t3s.svg" alt="" class="logo">
        </div>
      </a>
    </nav>
    <main>
      <div class="main-wrapper">
        <div class="title-wrapper">
          <h1>Menaxhimi i burimeve njerëzore</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
          <a href="">
            <div class="box-btn"></div>
          </a>
          <a href="">
            <div class="box-btn"></div>
          </a>
          <a href="">
            <div class="box-btn"></div>
          </a>
          <a href="">
            <div class="box-btn"></div>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </main>
</body>

</html>
```

I tried to change some css in the grey area. Is this what you want? If you want an element to be on the bottom, you can set `bottom: 0;` to its css when positioned `absolute`.

Comment: It's working now but the links still stretch vertically and on smaller screens the last box doesn't have space at the bottom anymore.

Comment: @gmodboi give the `.content` class some bottom padding

Comment: i can see the cursor changes to pointer only when it is inside the box area. previously it used to be pointer vene outside the box. You can use pointer-events for quick-fix as answered by @isabella-capilla

Comment: nvm, all i had to do was wrap the links in div containers.

Answer (score 1):

I would add to your most external container the css property `pointer-events: none` and to the internal one `pointer-events:all`. If what you want is not giving click feature to the external containers, this might solve the issue.

```
.content > a {
pointer-events: none;
}

.box-btn {
pointer-events: all;
}
```

Comment: Now I can't click them at all.

Comment: are you sure you added it for the right components? I tested here and works in the codepen you sent simply by adding these lines of code in the end of your css. https://codepen.io/Bellinha/pen/GREoeVd